# Laravel authentication does not set me as authenticated

Tags: php, laravel

I'm pretty fresh into laravel. I've used CakePHP a time or two, but not this.

Currently I'm trying to make a authentication system. The registration does work, so does logging in.

When I log in, my view gets displayed. But when I try to secure the controllers functions by using the `auth` middleware:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware("auth");
}
```

it keeps redirecting me to `/`, but when it isn't there, it all works?

Also, when I try to do `var_dump(Auth::check());` in the login function, it shows `true`, but when I do it in my index (Where i keep getting wrongfully redirected to) it shows `false`.

This is how I log in my users:

```
public function postLogin(LoginRequest $request) {
    if ($this->auth->attempt($request->only("username", "password"))) {
        return redirect("/me");
    }

    return redirect("/")->withInput()->withErrors([
        "username" => "The credentials you entered did not match out system."
    ]);
}
```

Is it because of a bug in the code that causes this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm making use of Laravel 5.2. And also as requested: here are the routes.

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'UnloggedController@index');
    Route::get('/me', 'MeController@index');
});

Route::controller('/','Auth\AuthController');
```

Comment: Do you have the `Session` middleware enabled? What session driver are you using?

Comment: @Pitchinnate `'web' => [ 'driver' => 'session', 'provider' => 'users', ],` Do you mean this? And the `session` middleware is included with the `web` group right?

Comment: @WesleyPeeters What Laravel version are you using? Also please post the route definition for that controller action.

Comment: @WesleyPeeters you would look in your .env file to see how your sessions are being managed. Yes I believe the session middleware is included in the web group by default. Does your route use the `web` group? Also just to make sure you are putting that `__construct()` function in your Controller correct?

Comment: @WesleyPeeters Move the `Route::controller('/','Auth\AuthController');` definition into the route group that has the `web` middleware added, otherwise the session will not be enabled for it and the authentication system needs the session in order to work.

Comment: @Pitchinnate My routes do use the `web` group. Also the `session_driver` is file

Comment: Are session files being written to `/storage/framework/sessions`? It could be a permissions issue with your web server.

Comment: @Pitchinnate Yes they are. Bogdans answer helped me a lot. Now i have to figure out why it shows CSRF token mismatch...

Comment: @Bogdan Thanks! Would you make this into an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: @WesleyPeeters The token mismatch error should be pretty easy to fix and in most cases it's because the token is not passed along with a non read http verb request (like POST, PUT, etc). The [Laravel CSRF Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing#csrf-x-xsrf-token) is pretty clear on what is needed there :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move `Route::controller` definition into the route group that has the `web` middleware added, otherwise the session will not be enabled for it and the authentication system needs the session in order to work. So it should be like this:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'UnloggedController@index');
    Route::get('/me', 'MeController@index');

    Route::controller('/','Auth\AuthController');
});
```